# Power BI Report measure jobs completed on time

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI report that calculates the number of jobs due in a month and reports on how many jobs are completed on time.  The report works well except I cannot figure out how to include jobs that were completed ahead of time a month early, as done on time.

I have measures in place for:

- Done on time = Jobs completed in their due month (this is where I need help with the code)
- Outside time = Jobs completed after when they were due.
- Incomplete = Used to identify incomplete jobs
- % Perf = Percentage of jobs completed on time."

Measure "Due":

```
Due = COUNTROWS ( Table1 )
```

Measure "Done on time":

```
Done on time = 
VAR DueMonth = MONTH ( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            MONTH ( Table1[completed] ) = DueMonth
        )
    )
```

Measure "Outside time":

```
Outside time = 
VAR DueMonth = MONTH ( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            MONTH ( Table1[completed] ) <> DueMonth && 
            NOT ISBLANK ( Table1[completed] )
        )
    )
```

Measure "Incomplete":

```
Incomplete = 
VAR DueMonth = MONTH ( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            ISBLANK ( Table1[completed] )
        )
    )
```

Measure "% Perf"

```
% Perf = 
    DIVIDE ( 
        [Done on time],
        [Due],
        BLANK()
    )
```

Expected results would be jobs completed early be added to the total jobs completed in the correct month.

Sample Output:
[Sample job data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGEjK.png)
[Sample Job Data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSfNa.png)

[image: Sample Report View]

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: See sample job data 2 screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand the question correctly, you want to change the metric to take into consideration all completed task ON or before the completion month:

```
    Done on time or prior= 
VAR DueMonth = MONTH ( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            MONTH ( Table1[completed] ) <= DueMonth
        )
    )
```

Or consider planned month and planned month -1:

```
    Done on time or month before= 
VAR DueMonth = MONTH ( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            MONTH ( Table1[completed] ) = DueMonth || MONTH ( Table1[completed] ) = DueMonth -1
        )
    )
```

Please take notice, that you might need take year into consideration as well. If that is so, I would suggest you try [eomonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/eomonth-function-dax) function like this:

```
Done on time or month before= 
VAR DueMonth = EOMONTH( FIRSTDATE ( Table1[due_date] ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        [Due],
        FILTER ( 
            Table1,
            EOMONTH( Table1[completed] ) = DueMonth || EOMONTH( Table1[completed] ) = dateadd(DueMonth, -1, month)
        )
    )
```